# Invalid IP Configuration error

Tags: networking, router

I am not sure if this is the right platform to ask this question, and please consider me a newbie.

I was using a ADSL modem given by BSNL (ISP).

I bought a D-Link WiFi ADSL Router(DSL-2730U) and the setup is now:
    Phone Line->D-link Modem+Router->PC

I set up the PC connection(The setup wizard was helpful).
I connect with my android phone via WiFi.

My PC was working fine until it was shut down. 
After that it shows the yellow warning thingy on the network icon.
After selecting troubleshooting, it says the error is

> Local Area Connection does not have a valid IP configuration

What is the problem?
PS: I checked IP of PC and mobile, It is different. PC has dynamic ip.

Edit: ipconfig /all when error shows
note: When there is no error, ip is: 192.168.1.34

Windows IP Configuration

Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : JaKe-PC
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
    Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
    **Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00**
    DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
    Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
    Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::3808:5cf0:c183:8408%13(Preferred)
    Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.132.8(Preferred)
    Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
    Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
    DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 184549376
    DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1B-AE-1C-0E-D0-27-88-5B-79-22

    DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                      fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
    NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Comment: Hey welcome to SU, so your configuration goes like this: Phone Line ADSL > Modem > D-Link Router > PC correct? When you say the IP's are different do you mean they are like 192.168.0.3 and 192.168.0.6 or are they completely different like 10.100.3.4 and 192.168.1.10? Basically trying to figure if the wireless and the cable are on the same IP Range.

Comment: thanks @CharlesH, It is a modem+router. So, Phone Line->D-link Modem+Router->PC... now the ip@mobile:192.168.1.34 and the ip@PC:192.168.1.33... But now the connection is working. It comes and goes every time PC is restarted..

Comment: Ah ok so its a modem router thats good it eliminates one element from the troubleshooting. OK so both are on the same IP Range which is good. When you restart and the connection is down (showing the error in your question) can you make this happen and then open the command prompt from the start menu and type ipconfig /all then post the results back in your question.

Comment: @CharlesH, added ipconfig results along with the question..

Comment: PS: Please see that, at the toime of error, the physical address is 00-00-00-00-00-00

Comment: Sorry for delay, Xmas and all that! Interesting results above, when the problem occurs can you try the same command ipconfig but with the switch /renew so its ipconfig /renew and see if you get a 192.168.x.x IP instead of 169.x.x.x thanks

Comment: @CharlesH, Sorry for the delay. ipconfig /renew returns an error.   `C:\Users\JaKe>ipconfig /renew 
Windows IP Configuration 
An error occurred while renewing interface Local Area Connection : unable to contact your DHCP server. Request has timed out.`

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies with your PCs network card. Sometimes it fails to show its MAC addess (see your line with Physical Address.  : 00-00-00-00-00-00).

The [MAC address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) is an unique 48 bits identifier, think of it as a serial number for a network card. This address is used by the Ethernet protocol and it **should** be valid. 00:00:00:00:00:00 is not valid.

I can only think of three ways for this to go wrong:

1. Error at the manufacturer. It should never have worked. (though it is possible the old setup was more forgiving).
2. Damage while changing your setup.
3. Some cards allow you to override the MAC with your own address. It then fall supon you to make sure that you have a legel and unique MAC for each networkcard on your local network. You mention some kind of wizard. Did that ask questions about cloning setting?